# how to close the jobs one by one? is there any options?

Tags: shell, kill, job-control

There is list of jobs running.

```
pdf is opened
image is opened
text file opened
```

It's all in fg/bg .

Is there any option to close the particular job forcefully? Also, I want to know if the jobs can be closed with the help of a command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the jobs were all started from your current shell: use 'jobs' to get a list of backgrounded jobs.  Each will have a numeric identifier, starting from '1'.  Then you can bring the job to the foreground with `fg %1`, send it to the background if it's paused with `bg %1`, or kill it with `kill %1` (use the correct number for the job you're trying to kill, of course).

```
$ jobs
$ sleep 20 &
[1] 1770
$ sleep 30 &
[2] 1771
$ sleep 40 &
[3] 1773
$ jobs
[1]   Running                 sleep 20 &
[2]-  Running                 sleep 30 &
[3]+  Running                 sleep 40 &
$ kill %2
$ jobs
[1]   Running                 sleep 20 &
[2]-  Terminated              sleep 30
[3]+  Running                 sleep 40 &
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 sleep 20 &
[3]+  Running                 sleep 40 &
$
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few basic tools for this, the most useful being `pgrep` and `pkill` but you should also have a look at `kill` and `killall`. Briefly, `pgrep` lets you search for processes and returns their [Process ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) (PID) and the other three let you kill processes. I will use `evince`, my PDF viewer for this example.

1. Get the PID of the process using `pgrep`:

   ```
   $ pgrep evince
   10834
   ```

   So, `evince` is running and has the PID 10834. Note that if you have multiple instances of `evince` open, you'll get many PIDs:

   ```
   $ pgrep evince
   10834
   11834
   11885
   ```
2. Kill the process by PID:

   ```
   $ pkill 10834
   ```
3. Kill all PID's returned by `pgrep evince`:

   ```
   $ kill $(pgrep evince)
   ```
4. Kill all processes named `evince`:

   ```
   killall evince
   ```

So, use `killall PROG_NAME` to kill all running instances of a program using it's name, eg. `killall firefox`. Use `pkill` or `kill` for single PIDs and `kill $(pgrep foo)` for many PIDs.

Comment: If they're shell jobs, it's more direct and less error-prone to use job designations, e.g. `kill %1`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can kill a single job with the PID assigned to a job.

For example a job ntpd

1º You have to get the PID of the job ntpd:

> ~$>ps aux | grep ntpd
>
> ntp 2911  0.0  0.0  30204  1204 ?        Ss   Oct15   0:03 ntpd -u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g
>
> root 14932  0.0  0.0 105348   864 pts/3    S+   18:19   0:00 grep --color ntpd

You can get the PID from the second column. That number is the PID assigned.

After this you only have to do is end it with kill command:

> ~$>kill 2911

There is more fancy ways but this is the faster in my opinion.

Comment: If they're shell jobs, it's more direct and less error-prone to use job designations, e.g. `kill %1`

Answer (score 0):

Basic command for delete process is :

> :~$ pkill -9 PROCESS_NAME

replace "PROCESS_NAME" with your process name that you want to kill. it kill all process that belong with the name of process.